# detect my apps been killed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have built a simple apps that connect to a sqlite database, and the app uses storyboards for UI. On first time, it will throw up a login view. If my authenticate was successful, I change my status in the sqlite database to 1. By default, it is 0. After login, I can use the app.

For example if I kill the app, how can I know my app has been killed? I need to change the status become default again. so whenever I click on the app again, I have to sign in again.

Any idea how to do this? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your application delegate implements several methods which handle state changes in your application. From the UIApplication.h header.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary  *)launchOptions NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
```

You can implement whichever methods are relevant, in this case the `applicationWillTerminate` method to change state. Alternatively, always throw up a login view in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. (This doesn't, however solve the issue updating the database. If the database is local, there's no problem, simply change the database before resigning or terminating. The challenge here would be if your database lives on a server. Although it might bot be an issue, I could see connection timeouts affecting the integrity of the remote values.)

These methods are added to your project automatically in your application delegate, which can be found in the AppDelegate.h & AppDelegate.m files.

For a complete explanation, have a look at the [UIApplication Delegate protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate:` will never be called when multitasking is enabled (which it is by default).

Comment: @omz - Is this the case even if a user manually terminates the app via the multitasking tray?

Comment: Yes, in that case the app is just killed.

Comment: @Moshe - yes.. i want to catch if the user manually terminates the app. is that also using the applicationWillTerminate? thanks.

Comment: No, according to @omz, you want to implement applicationWillResignActive.

Comment: but i never go to applicationWillTerminate.. I already tried to update the database. i mean i put my database update at applicationWillTerminate. but never got called. any idea?

Comment: Put it in applicationWillResignActive.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform close down actions in,

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Log out?
}
```

You can also do the same if your app isn't killed but just gets suspended, such as during an incoming call,

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Log out?
}
```

or,

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Log out?
}
```

Alternatively, on resume,

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Log in?
}
```

or,

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Log in?
}
```

Comment: (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application -> i use this if i terminate the apps right? My case here is the user manually terminates the apps. :)

Comment: i tried. but i never call the applicationWillTerminante. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect if you app was killed, since the process of you app gets killed by the system and no code is called to inform your app that it has been killed.

What you want is to set te some kins of boolean in :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Since this is called if you restart the app after it has been killed.

For the other states seen the answer by [Moshe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233623/309925)

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

use the delegate methods
such as:

```
applicationWillResignActive
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.. but i'm using ARC.. how can i handle the dealloc? thanks.

Comment: The `dealloc` method is implemented in a UIViewController, so it's not going to catch when your app closes in all cases.

Comment: @woz what are you talking about? `-dealloc` is called for all objects at some point or another, whenever the reference count reaches zero. Your `AppDelegate` is not special in that regard, dealloc will be called, the only question is when.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The `dealloc` method is obviously not the way to handle this.

Comment: @woz oh I agree wholeheartedly. But that doesn't mean that you **can't** catch the exit there either.  Your statement that it won't be called is false.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII It won't always be called if you implement it as a method of any UIViewController. I was the first to post the correct answer to this question, but you won't leave it alone. I'll delete my answer and you can post your own for me to nitpick, since you know all things iOS.

Comment: btw i tried to caught by putting the log at applicationWillTerminate. but never got call when i terminate my apps. any idea?